# What fonts do iPhone applications support?

Tags: iphone, fonts

I found a list of iPhone supported font here
http://daringfireball.net/misc/2007/07/iphone-osx-fonts

But I just wanted to confirm that, can we use all this fonts in application, or we are restricted to some class of fonts.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be able to use any of those fonts, provided you know the appropriate name. There are calls to enumerate the font families and individual fonts in those families on the phone, but a complete listing is available [on this site](http://iosfonts.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the blog post you're linking to has been converted to a parked domain. :(

Comment: http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/iphone_fonts

Comment: Note that the Daring Fireball article is pretty old. See http://iosfonts.com for a current list.

Comment: And go into the wayback machine if you're looking for an older iOS list, e.g. 4.2. (waybackmachine.org and enter http://iosfonts.com)

Comment: Here's a [direct link](http://web.archive.org/web/20101225135539/http://iosfonts.com//) for 4.2 fonts on iosfonts.com (snapshot from 25 Dec 2010)

Answer (score 24):

There is a free iPhone app called "Fonts" that will display all the installed fonts.  (To download it, [click this iTunes link](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=285217489&mt=8).)

But note that the fonts installed on your personal iPhone or simulator may not be the same as the set of fonts installed on other devices.

Comment: Nice app!  Ignore the low reviews by non-devs...

Comment: This app rules!  Nice job by the dev!

Answer (score 22):

Use the below code for getting all the fonts in system

// Get all the fonts on the system

```
NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];

for( NSString *familyName in familyNames ){
    printf( "Family: %s \n", [familyName UTF8String] );

    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    for( NSString *fontName in fontNames ){
        printf( "\tFont: %s \n", [fontName UTF8String] );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a good list of iPhone supported fonts, with their "real" names that you need to use in code: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2008/10/05/snippet-available-uifonts/.

Answer (score 1):

I created [iFonts](http://itunes.apple.com/app/ifonts/id392614957) so I could email the list to a designer. It's compatible all the way down to 3.0, so you can see what fonts are available on different versions of iOS, and you don't have to worry about whether a web page is accurate or complete. It's been tested all the way up to iOS 7.