# Which are the fonts available in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, uifont

I want to know which all fonts are currently supported by iphone sdk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What fonts iPhone application support.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249251/what-fonts-iphone-application-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.lightvoid.net/2008/11/02/iphone-uifont-list/

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code snippet in your application.

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSLog(@"Supported fonts : %@",familyNames);
```

And check your log. You can find all the fonts which are currently supported iOS.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.michaelcritz.com/2010/04/02/fonts-for-ipad-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

http://daringfireball.net/misc/2007/07/iphone-osx-fonts