# Change the Font of label "Comic-Sans-Ms"

Tags: objective-c, uifont

i think this is really basic question but i try many way to change the font of UILabel 
i try this code

```
lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 100)];
[lbl setText:@"Demo Text"];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Comic-Sans-Ms" size:20]];
```

but it's not work can you please tell me why i am not getting "Comic Sans Ms" font in my label. with this code other font are working but i don't know what is problem with **"Comic-Sans-MS"**

Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What fonts do iPhone applications support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249251/what-fonts-do-iphone-applications-support)

Comment: For those looking for a comparable font that is iOS-supported, try `ChalkboardSE-Bold`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [custom fonts](http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635).

Comment: While this may in principle answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to summarize the information you linked to in your post here.

Answer (score 0):

I take it this is iOS? It would then be because [Comic Sans is not installed on iOS](http://iosfonts.com/).